# Spaced string variable as command parameter inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, tar

How can I store a spaced string in a variable and use it as a command parameter inside a shell script?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
DESTINATION='/mnt/External Harddisk'
FILE_NAME=$DESTINATION/home.tar.gz
INCREMENTAL=$DESTINATION/home.snar

tar -zcvpf $FILE_NAME \
--directory=/home \
--listed-incremental=$INCREMENTAL \
--exclude=.gvfs \
--exclude=.cache* \
--exclude=*/[Cc]ache* \
--exclude=.thumbnails* \
--exclude=*/[Tt]rash* \
--exclude=*~ \
--exclude=.dropbox* \
--exclude=*.vdi \
--exclude=*VirtualBox*VMs* \
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this answer might cover it [Spaces in Linux environmental variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/616351/spaces-in-linux-environmental-variables)

You put the environment variable in double quotes. example demonstrating that below

I am doing `ls 'asdf asdf'` which is ls on one file 'adsf asdf' with a space in the filename. I want to do it with a variable. You see with double quotes it gets the result. With no quotes it treats the space as special and looks for the file asdf twice. And with single quotes `ls '$f'` it looks for literal dollar f. But with double quotes `ls "$f"` it works, i.e. gives same result as `ls 'asdf asdf'`.

```
$ ls 'asdf asdf' <ENTER>
ls: cannot access asdf asdf: No such file or directory

$ export f='asdf asdf' <ENTER>

$ echo $f <ENTER>
asdf asdf

$ ls $f <ENTER>
ls: cannot access asdf: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access asdf: No such file or directory

$ echo $f <ENTER>
asdf asdf

$ ls '$f' <ENTER>
ls: cannot access $f: No such file or directory


$ ls "$f" <ENTER>
ls: cannot access asdf asdf: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1):

Prepend any Space character with Escape string, so the Space will be in the string as '\ ' (backslash + space). Hope this help.

Comment: what do you mean? like this? doesn't work http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bCa90GYe

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes before substituting variables, so putting quotes and/or escapes in the values of variables doesn't do anything useful. You need to put double-quotes *around* the variable reference.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: Give an example and test it. You might even try it and find it doesn't work.